# Got error after migration from rspec-rails 2.x to 3.x

Tags: rspec-rails, rspec3

Before migration these steps passed, but now I get errors:

```
Failures:

  1) RegistrationPayment .opts
     Failure/Error: allow(Rails.configuration).to receive(:pim_product_url).and_return(product_url)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/lib/registration_payment_spec.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) RegistrationPayment .new
     Failure/Error: allow(Rails.configuration).to receive(:pim_product_offerings).and_return([offering_id])
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/lib/registration_payment_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I define `product_url` and `offering_id` such way

```
  let(:product_url) { '/product/url' }
  let(:offering_id) { '3000319' }
```

Comment: Something is expecting one argument but receiving two: `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`. It might help to see the code from the example to determine what is causing that.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a bug in Rails 3.  It has since been fixed in Rails 4:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ba5fab4c015366e355ab92371b27e77e896124a4

TL;DR; respond_to? should accept 2 arguments, but the configuration class in Railties does not.

Comment: It was fixed in Rails 4.1, not 4 :sadpanda:

Comment: Correction: It was fixed in Rails 4.0.10.